# Comparing the "Size" of 2 LIbraries

Tags: ruby, image, docker, containers

If I wanted to compare the size of 2 libraries, say Sinatra vs. Rails, what would be the most accurate way to do that?

I was thinking of creating the following 2 docker images and comparing their sizes, but wasn't sure if I needed to compare the image, the container, or neither (for whatever reason):
A - {Base Stuff} + Ruby + Sinatra
B - {Base Stuff} + Ruby + Rails

Is that a good approach or would I want to do something different?

Comment: How do you define "size"?  Is it specific to Ruby?  Does it include dependent gems?  I wouldn't unnecessarily introduce Docker into this; you can get simpler isolation through a Bundler vendor tree or an rbenv or rvm gemset.

Comment: What about building the same application with both frameworks and comparing the code you have to write and the efford it takes?

Comment: Why would you get simpler isolation via rbenv or rvm gemset? Are you guaranteed to have that isolated from your system ruby gems? I think so, but just wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways in which you can technically compare library sizes but the real question is what do you get out of these comparisons.

Sinatra is "smaller" than Rails in pretty much every metric you can think of:

- Lines of code
- Memory usage by code
- Memory usage of your application if you use the library
- Number of dependencies
- Lines of code in library + dependencies
- Memory usage of library + dependencies

Sinatra also does a lot less than Rails (and I think it's accurate to say that everything that Sinatra does, Rails does too in some way).

But this comparison isn't easily generalized to arbitrary libraries because of the number of axes. Consider library A that is a thin wrapper around library C, and a library B:

- Library A has fewer lines of code than library B
- Library A + dependencies has more lines of code than library B

When you use either A or B they both utilize their dependencies, so which one is "smaller"?

Or, compare a pure Ruby library like net/http with a library like curb that is backed by a C extension or a C library. The pure Ruby library may have fewer lines of code but greater memory footprint and lower performance. The C library may have vastly more lines of code and higher performance and smaller memory footprint. But if you compare curb without curl (the backing C library) to net/http maybe curb has fewer lines of code.